# Select multiple blocks of nodes including the start and end nodes with XPath 1.0

Tags: php, xpath

The following is a simplified version of my XML:

```
<div><p class="start">1</p></div>
<div><p class="data">2</p></div>
<div><p class="data">3</p></div>
<div><p class="end">4</p></div>
<div><p class="data">5</p></div>
<div><p class="start">6</p></div>
<div><p class="data">7</p></div>
<div><p class="end">8</p></div>
```

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
<?php
...
$start_nodes = $finder->query('//div[p/@class="start"]');
foreach ($start_nodes as $node) {
  $data_nodes = $finder->query('following-sibling::div[p/@class="end"][1]/preceding-sibling::*', $node);
  ...
}
```

I don't know how to select the `<div><p class="start"/></div>` node, the next `<div><p class="end"/></div>` node and all the nodes in between. In the above example I want to get 1-4, then 6-8 and skip 5.

I'm using XPath 1.0 in PHP and it's not XLST.

Comment: I think that in no way :( you should scan nodes untill `<div><p class="end"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
$start_nodes = $finder->query('//div[p/@class="start"]');
foreach ($start_nodes as $node) {
    $count = $finder->evaluate('count(preceding-sibling::div[p/@class="start"])', $node)+1;
    echo 'start '. $count .' : <br>';
    $start = 'self::*';
    $end = 'following-sibling::div[p/@class="end"][1]';
    $inbetween = 'following-sibling::div[p/@class="end"][1]/preceding-sibling::*[count(preceding-sibling::div[p/@class="start"])='.$count.']';
    $data_nodes = $finder->query($start.' | '.$inbetween.' | '.$end, $node);
    foreach($data_nodes as $d){
        echo $d->nodeValue .", ";
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

`$data_nodes` in above is the result of union (`|`) of three separate xpath expressions; first xpath is for selecting 'start element' (`$start`), the second is for selecting 'end element' (`$end`), and the last is for selecting elements between start and end elements (`$inbetween`).

**<kbd>[Demo](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/D3IU9p)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
start 1 :
1, 2, 3, 4,

start 2 :
6, 7, 8,
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I changed `self::*` to `.` and it seems to work fine!